# anyone can help me with SSO AZURE login?

Tags: azure, authentication, redirect, token, single-sign-on

I´m having problem with SSO from Azure. I am using azure to get their token, and then send it to our own backend in order to get the auth to login. To do this, I am using useMsal,and following the popup strategy "const response = await instance.loginPopup(loginRequestPopup)". When the user want to login with azure, a popup appear, users choose the account, I receive the token, this is sent to my Backend and that it is. The problem, sometimes when the user choose the account in this new azure tab, this tab instead of close it self, this redirect to the login screen and doesn´t generate de token. After that all fail. someone can help me with this? bellow I will show you my code.

functions:

```
export const handleAzureLogin = async ({ instance, loginRequestPopup, inProgress }: IAzureLogIn) => {
  try {
    const response = await instance.loginPopup(loginRequestPopup)
    const jwtToken = response.idToken
    console.log('JWT Token:', jwtToken)
    const bodyRequest = {
      type: 2,
      ssoToken: jwtToken,
    }
    const res = await sendTokenToBackend(bodyRequest)
    if (res.status === StatusCodes.OK) {
      return res
    } else {
      // Manejar el error del backend
      console.log('Backend error:', res)
      return res
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    // Manejar errores en el proceso de inicio de sesión de Azure
    console.error('Azure login error:', error)

    return {
      status: StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, // Ajusta el código de estado según sea necesario
      body: error.message,
    }
  }
}

export const sendTokenToBackend = async (bodyRequest: IBodyRequest) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyRequest),
    })

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`)
    }

    return {
      status: 200,
      body: response,
    }
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log('Error sending token to backend:', err)
    return {
      status: 400,
      body: err.message,
    }
  }
}
```

```
export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_CLIENT_ID}`,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_KEY}`,
    redirectUri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_URL_REDIRECT}`,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message)
            return
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message)
            return
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message)
            return
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message)
            return
          default:
            return
        }
      },
    },
  },
}

export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ['api://f50ace46-b2a0-4394-8d3d-8d72116f743c/Public.Read'],
}

export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Public.Read',
}

export const loginRequestPopup = {
  ...loginRequest,
  prompt: 'select_account',
}
```

thank you in advance!

I want to avoid that weird behivor and get the login for the user.

redirect it is not working, and all the login fails. I want to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Nest try catch to get silent token from cache or if expired use Interactive/Popup:

```
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
     result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                       .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
    // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
    Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                          .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalException msalex)
    {
        ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
    return;
}

if (result != null)
{
    string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
    // Use the token
}
```

I understand you are using Angular, try something like this:

```
 MsalModule.forRoot(
        new PublicClientApplication({
            auth: {
                clientId: environment.azure.clientId,
                authority: environment.azure.cloudInstance + environment.azure.tenantId,
                redirectUri: environment.azure.redirectUri,
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
            },
        }),
        {
            interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
            authRequest: {
                scopes: ["user.read"],
            },
        },
        {
            interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
            protectedResourceMap: new Map([
                ['/', [`${environment.azure.clientId}/openid`]],
            ]),
        }
    ),
```

Comment: Hi Juanme, first of all thank you so much for your help. But unfortunately I am getting the same error. It is so weird, because it is working and time to time, after choosing the account to go back to the login screen all fail, this new tab instead of close it self , appear login screen so I have two tabs with my login screen, and nothing happen.